# Watching Expression in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, expression, nslog

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Badger"])
    {
        self.currentBusiness=nil;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Title"])
    {
        self.currentBusiness.Title=self.currentProperty;
        NSLog(@"self.currentBusiness.Title=%@",self.currentBusiness.Title);
    }
}
```

Okay The NSlog correctly print  BadgerNew[2516:207] self.currentBusiness.Title=Martabak Telor India

Which is correct.

But if I add expression on the watch window and put

self.currentBusiness.Title

I got nothing. In fact, there is no way to know that self.currentBusiness.Title=@"Martabak Telor India" without NSLog

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Check your "Active Configuration" in Xcode, it should be Debug.

Also go to project setting -> build. Under GCC 4.2 - Code Generation check "Generate debug symbols", set "Optimization Level" to "None" and "Level of Debug Symbols" to "All Symbols".

Hope this will help.

Comment: Where do I see Active Configuration?

Comment: If you're using Xcode 3, then Project -> set Active Build Configuration -> Debug.

Comment: Done all that. [url=http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/33411100/file.html][img=http://www51.zippyshare.com/scaled/33411100/file.html][/img][/url] Still same problem.

Comment: http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/33411100/file.html http://www51.zippyshare.com/scaled/33411100/file.html

Comment: And what does it show when you expand `self.currentBusiness`?

Comment: BTW, you can print your variables directly from debug window. Don't really sure about Xcode 4, but in Xcode 3 one can right-click on variable in debug window and select "Print Description to Console"

Comment: Well it's a core data object. So it shows that self.currentBusiness has one "member" (or parent, which is a member) with type NSManagedObject.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way. I already voted up. But well, I am still curious on why Apple didn't work this out. Notice that self.CurrentProperty shows the result. But self.CurrentBusiness.Title doesn't.

Comment: So, printing `self.CurrentBusiness.Title` to console from debugger doesn't work either? I'm really curious about this issue of core data objects.